# Argument not optional, str =

Tags: excel, vba

Why when I want to debug, it will error at

```
If Emp8.Value = True Then
    str = "Whatsapp, "
End If
```

and it will appear;

> Argument not optional

Basically what I want to do is, I want to edit data in the user form.

```
Private Sub cmdEdit_Click()

If Me.Emp1 = "" Then
Call MsgBox("The fields are not complete", vbInformation, "Edit Contact")
Exit Sub
End If

Set findvalue = Sheet1.Range("b8:b10000").Find(What:=Me.Emp1, LookIn:=xlValues)

findvalue.Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.Emp1.Value

If Emp8.Value = True Then
    str = "Whatsapp, "
End If

If Emp12.Value = True Then
    str = str & "SMS, "
End If

If Emp11.Value = True Then
    str = str & "Email, "
End If

If Emp10.Value = True Then
    str = str & "Facebook, "
End If

If Emp9.Value = True Then
    str = str & "Phone Call, "
End If
str = Left(str, Len(str) - 2)
    findvalue.Offset(0, 2) = str

If Emp2.Value = True Then
    findvalue.Offset(0, 3) = "Yes"
ElseIf Emp3.Value = True Then
    findvalue.Offset(0, 3) = "No"
End If

findvalue.Offset(0, 4).Value = Me.Emp4.Value
findvalue.Offset(0, 5).Value = Me.Emp5.Value
findvalue.Offset(0, 6).Value = Me.Emp6.Value
findvalue.Offset(0, 7).Value = Me.Emp7.Value

Call MsgBox("The contact has been updated", vbInformation, "Edit Contact")

On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: How is `str` defined? What type is that variable? Or is it a function or procedure? Make always use of `Option Explicit` and declare all your variables correctly like `Dim str As String`.

Comment: You haven't declared str variable in your code.

Comment: you have many lines with `str =`, could you be more specific about what you're trying to do, what's happening, and what you've tried.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thankyou :)

Comment: @ImranMalek Orait, thanks :)

Comment: `Str` is a VBA function. Since you haven't declared a `str` variable to override that, the compiler assumes you mean the function, which requires an argument. I'd suggest you use a different name for your variable as well as declaring them as @Pᴇʜ said.

Comment: @ashleedawg at whatsapp area, but nah its okay. i already got the answer. thanks :)

Comment: @Rory yes, thanks ya! :)